# Laravel: Import Csv file with Maatwebsite Excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to upload a csv file using `Maatwebsite\Excel`. When i'm uploading an `Excel` file it works fine but when i'm trying to upload a csv file i'm having an error `Undefined offset: 1`.

The problem i think is with the delimiter of the csv file (Where the delimiter is a `;`), when i `var_dump($row)` of the excel file i have this result `array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "user1CSV" [1]=> string(11) "a@gmail.com" [2]=> string(9) "azerty&23" }` but with the csv file the result is `array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "user1CSV;a1@gmail.com;azerty&23" }`.

How can i set the delimiter to accept `Excel` and `Csv` delimiters? My code is :

**The controller**

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Imports\UsersImport;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function fileImportExport()
    {
        return view('file-import');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function fileImport(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
        return back();
    }
}
```

**The import class**

```js
class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        var_dump($row);
        return new User([
            'name'     => $row[0],
            'email'    => $row[1],
            'password' => Hash::make($row[2])
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your delimiter should be `;` then.

Comment: @nice_dev how can i do that ? accept Excel and csv delimiters

Comment: does this help: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-csv-settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/excel.php` file you can set `delimiter` in `csv` array as `;`

You can check full `config/excel.php` file here: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/config/excel.php

And on line 45 there is a `csv.delimiter` setting, set `,` by default. You just need to change it to `;`
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/config/excel.php#L45

If you want to set custom csv settings for each of your Import class; as I can see from Laravel Excel documentation you can set custom csv delimiter: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-csv-settings.html#available-settings

In your `app\Imports\UsersImport.php` file you can set your `delimiter` as `;` by adding this method:

```
public function getCsvSettings(): array
{
    return [
        'delimiter' => ";"
    ];
}
```